# Удалить информацию плагина из анонса (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

На моем сайте установлен плагин Seriously Simple Podcasting.
Так вот когда к записи добавляешь ссылку на файл подкаста wordpress отображает текст ссылки в анонсе к записи на главной странице. Кто знает как избавиться от этой ссылки в анонсе?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Кто знает как избавиться от этой ссылки в анонсе?

Для текста анонса использовать поле "отрывок"

Включается в настройках экрана.

[image: настройка отрывка]

Comment: Не помогает. Я так понял что "Отрывок" не подключен в моем шаблоне. Надо разобраться как его подключить.

Comment: @АртемНовиков Значит у тебя выводит не анонс, а контент. См функции the_excerpt и the_content

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. Слегка подправил шаблон и все получилось как нужно.